# How to delete extra mesh created

Tags: mesh

How do delete or select the extra mesh created. I cant select or delete the face created. I have remove doubles. There is no edge to the face. Any suggestion or help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: No way to delete it. Convert Ngons to quads or at least tris

Comment: @MrZak i tried to make tris and then quad but the geometry is deleting faces and mesh getting disturb also increases the verts

Answer (score 4):

The reason for the 'extra mesh' is that your object has a number of large, uneven faces with more than 4 edges. In cases like this, blender has a hard time filling the face in, since it's both not perfectly flat, and it's an odd shape. N-gons are actually converted to triangles before being displayed and rendered, as graphics cards can't actually deal with anything but triangles. If you select the face that's causing you problems ant press Ctrl-T to convert it to triangles in the viewport you'll see what your problem is. Blender is automatically triangulating the n'gon (as it should) and due to the large, uneven nature of the face one of the triangles is going outside the perimeter of the face,

As MrZak mentioned, the only real solution to this problem is to ensure your mesh is only tris or quads (preferable quads). N-gons can be used in certain cases, but they usually work best in cases where all of the edges are convex and the face is perfectly flat. otherwise you still risk issues like you are experiencing.

I took a quick look at your model, and I'm going to make the unfortunate recommendation of taking a step back, thinking about your end goal, watching/reading some tips about modelling, and then having another go at creating your wall. The way your wall is currently made will only cause you headaches down the road, and being able to make a nice, clean topology wall like you are going for here will be great practice and a good skill to have.